# How to set a LocationRectangle on Universal Windows Platform map control?

Tags: dictionary, location, mapping, uwp, windows-10-universal

I am developing an app in which I have a Map control! On this map, I am adding custom pushpins via map.Children property. How can I set a LocationRectangle and then zoom on it? Because I want my pushpins not to be out of the screen size. I want the map to zoom on a level in which all of the pins will be on the screen!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `MapControl`'s `TrySetViewBoundsAsync` method. This method allows you to specify a bounding box of the area you want to display (which you can calculate by finding the the farthest pushpins in all directions, which will give you the north-west and south-east corner of the area), a potential margin and a map animation to use while the view is being changed.

You can find more details about the method [in the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn637065.aspx).